# python - find possible combination from item and number of Number of reps

Tags: python, list, math, combinations

I have a dictionary with items and the number of reps for each item, for example:

```
{A: 3, B: 1}
```

I'm looking for a way to get all possible **different** combinations,
The order doesn't matter: `[AB]` is the same as `[BA]`.

The wanted output is:

```
[A, AA, AAA, B, AB, AAB, AAAB]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using list comprehensions and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product, chain
d = {'A': 3, 'B': 1}
l = [[k*i for i in range(1,v+1)] for k, v in d.items()]
[''.join(element) for element in product(*l)] + list(chain.from_iterable(l))
```

**Output:**

```
['AB', 'AAB', 'AAAB', 'A', 'AA', 'AAA', 'B']
```

**Details:**

The result of the first list comprehension is a nested list where each sublist has each of the `keys` contained in the dictionary repeated from `1` up to its corresponding `value`:

```
[['A', 'AA', 'AAA'], ['B']]
```

The second one, performs the cartesian product using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), and each product is `joined` into a string. Finally a flattened version of `l` is added using `chain.from_iterable`:

```
print(list(chain.from_iterable(l)))
['A', 'AA', 'AAA', 'B']

[''.join(element) for element in product(*l)]
['AB', 'AAB', 'AAAB']
```